# Load dc.js dashboard in multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, dc.js

I'm presently working on dc.js dashboard and i'm struck in the middle of some new ask from my team. Is there a way where we can have multiple tabs on my html page and each tab renders respective dashboard data.

I was googling and came across something similar but its in d3.
Here is the link http://bl.ocks.org/widged/4561185

Please let me know what sort of code changes should i need to make to achieve this functionality.

Comment: This isn't really a dc.js question - if you use bootstrap for the tabs, then just put a chart div inside each tab (as in the example) and they will interact just the same as if the divs were side-by-side. It might be confusing if you allow brushing/filtering in the charts inside the tabs, because the filter could become hidden?